# Doxygen c parse error

Tags: c, doxygen

I am adding doxygen comments to a group of c source files, and getting an error in the documentation when the following definitions are parsed.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//!@brief Checks if the system is ready to insert a given field and compiles a removal list.
//!@param[in] inField - pointer to the field being inserted.
//!@return true, if the system is ready to insert the field
//!@note
//! <pre>
//! Removal list: a list of fields overlapped by the incoming field.
//! A fields insert will not be allowed to enter the display frame if:
//!     1. The insert is a standard field and it overlaps fixed content.
//!     2. The insert is not using the immediate replace option and the field it overlaps has not finished its effects.
//! </pre>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static bool
CheckInsertReady( pField inField )
{
    // process ...

    return( allReady );
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//!@brief Used to access a sequence structure.
//!@param[in] seq - sequence ID
//!@return pointer to the structure or NULL if validation fails.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public pSeq
GetSeq( ulong seq )
{
    // process ...
    return( NULL );
}
```

[image]

Some warnings:

[image]

Can anyone suggest any possible issues?

IDE:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: It seems to be more of an IDE problem than a problem with Doxygen itself? If so, then what is your IDE?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added information on the IDE to the question.

Comment: When you run doxygen outside the IDE what does doxygen report. Btw. which version of doxygen are you using? Did you rename the field to inField and not rerun doxygen?

Comment: I haven't tried running Doxygen outside of the IDE yet (will give it a go). No renaming, but there are many routines with the parameter 'field'.

Comment: The version is 1.8.14 and I get the same issue running via Doxygen wizard.

Comment: This is strange, does it give a filename? Is there another file that defines the same routine (checkInsertReady) ?

Comment: This looks like a Eclipse problem. Probably it's a variant of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041453 If Eclipse thinks that there is (was?) a parameter `field` then the Eclipse cache probably need an update.

Comment: Cheers for the help lads - looking for possible issues with declarations in the c source.

Comment: @albert there shouldn't be, but having a look at the build logs.

Comment: @harper I will have a look at the question now and see.

Comment: I managed to get the document to build the section in the question correctly, but I haven't figured out the cause of the warning above (I have multiple cases with similar issues). The main error was code related.

Comment: I found a few typos that seem to tidy up many of the issues. Things like unknown tags, errors closing <pre> tag, and unknown escape codes. The unknown cases were comments where < and > were used and not escaped.